# Gtk3+ Spinbutton in vertical orientation (c/c++)

Tags: c++, c, gtk3

I'm pretty sure there is a easy way to do this… but I'm not so proficient with `GTK3 (coding in C/C++)` at this moment, and i'm finding myself stuck looking how can I create a new `GtkSpinButton` having the "+" and "-" buttons upper and below the entry text box instead as they are shown by default (at the right side of text entry).

I looked around in the documentation and a bunch of websites without look, but I see that there are `spinbutton.horizontal` and `spinButton.vertical` CSS classes… so I think there should be a way to simply instantiate the widget programmatically in `vertical` mode instead of `horizontal`.

Any help/hints on this, please?

Answer (score 3):

Well… after a bit more research, I did find/learn about the `GtkOrientable` interface and `GtkSpinButton` being one of the widgets implementing this, so `gtk_orientable_set_orientation()` did the trick!

Comment: Check [this Videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVq4LMp7pvr63lHOLjXJR5nO) if you need to learn more about that.